# .Net: How to I get Custom Attributes using TypeDescriptor.GetProperties?

Tags: .net, custom-attributes, typedescriptor

I have created my own attribute to decorate my object.

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class MyCustomAttribute : System.Attribute { }
```

When I try to use TypeDescriptor.GetProperties passing in my custom attribute it doesn't return anything even though the type is decorated with the attribute.

```
  var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(
              type, 
              new[] { new Attributes.FlatLoopValueInjection()});
```

**How do I get TypeDescriptor.GetProperties to recognize my custom types?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Type.GetProperties(type, Attributes[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yx7k228.aspx) method returns only the collection of **properties** for a specified type of component using a specified array of attributes as a filter.
Are you sure target type has **a properties marked with your custom attributes**, like this?

```
//...
    var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Person), new Attribute[] { new NoteAttribute() });
    PropertyDescriptor nameProperty = props["Name"];
}
//...
class Person {
    [Note]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
//...
class NoteAttribute : Attribute {
/* implementation */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**updated to get property attribute**

this code was copy and pasted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4a92379.aspx), which was the first result of the google search '[get customattribute reflection c#](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS444US444&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=get%20customattribute%20reflection%20c#)'

```
using System;

public class ExampleAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string stringVal;

    public ExampleAttribute()
    {
        stringVal = "This is the default string.";
    }

    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringVal; }
        set { stringVal = value; }
    }
}

[Example(StringValue="This is a string.")]
class Class1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof (Class1).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == "Foo").FirstOrDefault();
        foreach (object attrib in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(attrib);
        }
    }

    [Example(StringValue = "property attribute")]
    public string Foo {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Not mine, but I think he is trying to access Attributes on Properties, not classes themselves.

Comment: `TypeDescriptor` can inject properties later. It's like an extensible version of Reflection. If `TypeDescriptor` _is_ what the OP needs, then this answer is wrong.